# PHP Session never ends because ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery

I have a web app that use ajax and execute every 10 seconds to update some data.
I set a PHP session that after 60 minutes of inactivity the php session dies and kick user out of the page, but in this page the session never expire, I guess this is because the Ajax call execute every 10 seconds and the server refresh the "timeout", my session works fine in other pages where I don't execute ajax. You guys think that my problem in this page is because the ajax calls every 10 seconds?

My Jquery code:

```
    delay(function(){
        check();
    }, 10000 );

    function check()
    {
      $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "lead.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(msg){
            //Do something
        }
      });
     }
```

Comment: Sure, you have answered your own question. If the problem is only in the page with ajax, and if it sends requests every 10s, it really resets the timeout. You can fix this by manually tracking session timeouts.

Comment: Based on your description of the situation, your evaluation of the problem seems accurate. Do you have a question that we can help you resolve?

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I keep tracking of the session or how can I kill the session after 30 minutes of inactivity?

Comment: @Aneri I'd be interested to know how the php page knows where the request has come from. Is a cookie, or other tracking device included in the http header?

Comment: is `lead.php` returns some confidential data? If not then try not to start session on this page or use Aneri's answer.

Comment: @dewd Sessions in PHP are (generally) based on a cookie called `PHPSESSID`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I will keep track of the sessions.

Comment: As everyone has said, the session will never expire because of your ajax request. However, I've post a answer that will do it no matter if the ajax requests are being made or not

Answer (score 2):

If you wants to close the session after X time, no matter if the ajax requests are being made, but only if the user has no activity on the page, you can use this code I'm using:

```
(function () {
    // After 30 minutes without moving the mouse, the user will be redirect to logout page
    var time2refresh = 30;
    // This is how many time the user has to be inactive to trigger the countdown of 30 minutes
    var timeInactive = .5;
    // This will store the timer in order to reset if the user starts to have activity in the page
    var timer = null;
    // This will store the timer to count the time the user has been inactive before trigger the other timer
    var timerInactive = null;
    // We start the first timer. 
    setTimer();
    // Using jQuery mousemove method 
    $(document).mousemove(function () {
            // When the user moves his mouse, then we stop both timers
        clearTimeout(timer);
        clearTimeout(timerInactive);
            // And start again the timer that will trigger later the redirect to logout
        timerInactive = setTimeout(function () {
            setTimer();
        }, timeInactive * 60 * 1000);
    });
    // This is the second timer, the one that will redirect the user if it has been inactive for 30 minutes
    function setTimer() {
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = "/url/to/logout.php";
        }, time2refresh * 60 * 1000);
    }
})();
```

So the logic of this function is this:

1) User log in into your site
2) After .5 minutes (30 seconds) of inactivity one countdown of 30 minutes will start 
3) If the user moves his mouse, both timers are reseted, and the first one start again.
4) If after the 30 minutes the user does not moves his mouse, then it will be redirected to the logout page, closing his session.

Comment: Great code, think I'm going to use your code but instead of mouseover I will have .click event.

Comment: @HelderAlvarez don't forget to mark this as solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess `lead.php` uses `session_start()`. You could remove it only in that file.

Or, on first initialization, save the current time to a session var, and then for each call, check if more than one hour has passed. If true, `session_destroy()`